# What exactly does IE's InPrivate browsing do and how secure is it?

Tags: security, browser, internet-explorer

I recently started using InPrivate browsing with IE8 but not sure exactly how well it prevents websites I visit from extracting information from my computer or browsing sessions. Only reason I'm using IE is because it integrates well with other Microsoft products I have installed like: Office and Outlook. Is there a better, more secure browser than IE?

EDIT: Adendum, This is a question I posted some time ago which is now the focus of the internet privacy debate!  I am very skeptical when it comes to surfing the net. Once a computer is linked to the outside world, it may be vulnerable to passive spying, attack, etc. thus reason why I have a physically separate computer, with no private/confidential data, exclusively for connecting to the internet. I JUST DON'T TRUST IT!

Comment: [What is InPrivate Browsing?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-is-InPrivate-Browsing)

Comment: Any reference to that "is now the focus of the internet privacy debate"?

Comment: Private browsing is intended for doing your business on other people’s PCs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/ie8-and-privacy)

> While InPrivate Browsing is active,
> the following takes place:

- New cookies are not stored

> - All new cookies become “session” cookies
> - Existing cookies can still be read
> - The new DOM storage feature behaves the same way
> - New history entries will not be recorded
> - New temporary Internet files will be deleted after the Private Browsing
>   window is closed
> - Form data is not stored
> - Passwords are not stored
> - Addresses typed into the address bar are not stored
> - Queries entered into the search box are not stored
> - Visited links will not be stored

So basically it's added security for public terminals or your pc. It doesn't prevent websites from getting information from your browser

Answer (score 2):

> but not sure exactly how well it prevents websites I visit from extracting information from my computer

It doesn't.

> Is there a better, more secure browser than IE?

Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, Opera. Take your pick.

Comment: that's what I suspected, thanx Sathya!

Comment: @Frank, but most, if not all browsers, don't limit plugins or add-ons in these private modes. Like Flash is not limited in storing anything while using private browsing. (Though Adobe once announced that new versions will obey the privacy settings; I don't know if that's true nowadays, but still then: it's up to the plugin or add-on to obey the setting; it's not the browser that is enforcing that.)

Comment: This whole thing about surfing the internet is very risky, that's why none of my production business systems ever get connected to the internet!.. there's no way to guarantee that someone can eavesdrop on your IP address. I just dont trust it, never will!

Answer (score 1):

Its not secure at all.  There is no tunnel from one end of a client browser to the server in use. Only is it more secure in a way that it doesnt store information on your computer.
There are many good links on this on the www.

This one covers use and setup, what is secure and what is not. 
http://cognitiveanomalies.com/how-inprivate-browsing-works/

This one covers more its workings locally on a pc.
http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/inprivate-browsing.html

Bottom line is.  It doesnt help with trojans, viruses and so on. Its a bit more secure but not so users can rely on it at all.
Hope this helps.